# Plotting bars of variable width in Matlab 2016b

Tags: matlab, plot

I have data organised as such a structure,

[image]

and I'd like to plot a bar-like chart more or less like this:
[image]

i.e., where each bar is :
- color-coded as per 'type'
- as wide (x axis units) as indicated by 'duration'
- as tall (y axis) as indicated by 'avg'

I tried to use the 'bar' function, however got confused since it does not allow setting the width of individual bars, only of all bars at the same time.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this plot in matlab? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `patch` or `area` and draw rectangles. This has the advantage of the legend be easily made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should produce what you are looking for:

```
C = {
    0   1   0       'M';
   11   3   3.667   'o';
   21   3   7       'm';
   15   5   3       'M'
};

T = cell2table(C,'VariableNames',{'Total' 'Duration' 'Average' 'Type'});

figure();
hold on;

off = 0;

for i = 1:height(T)
    dur = T.Duration(i);
    avg = T.Average(i);

    switch (T.Type{i})
        case 'M'
            col = [1.0 0.0 0.0];
        case 'm'
            col = [0.0 1.0 0.0];
        case 'o'
            col = [0.0 0.0 1.0];
        otherwise
            col = [1.0 1.0 1.0];
    end

    rectangle('Position',[off 0 dur avg],'FaceColor',col);
    off = off + dur;
end

h = zeros(3,1);
h(1) = area(NaN,'FaceColor',[1.0 0.0 0.0]);
h(2) = area(NaN,'FaceColor',[0.0 1.0 0.0]);
h(3) = area(NaN,'FaceColor',[0.0 0.0 1.0]);
legend(h,'M','m','o');

hold off;
```

[image: Output]

I basically used the [rectangle function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) in order to plot consecutive rectangles over the axis, and exploited its `FaceColor` parameter in order to achieve a type-based colorization. For what concerns the legend, I created a fake one using a dummy area plot for every unique type and its respective color.

In my example I used a table to handle the sample data, but iterating over an array of structures is almost the same. Adjusting the axis ticks or the colors to fit your needs should not be difficult, but if you have doubts feel free to ask.

Comment: Spoke too soon, as your solution already ensures that the x axis is labelled like that. Many thanks! May I just nitpick and ask whether you have an idea how I can use the Data Cursor in the figure? It is a tool I use very often to do sanity checks and analyses on my plots, and it is one that in this case is not operational, since the plot is graphics- rather than data-based. In either case, great answer, thanks again!

Comment: Very ingenious way to create the legend too, by the way! Complimentoni!! :)

Comment: Thanks :) Anyway... for what concerns the Data Cursor, I think it cannot be useful in this case. You may try converting rectangle calls into area calls and see if they can produce data that is easier to validate, but I doubt. Actually, a solid algorithm should dissipate your doubts together with an eye check.